# Wrap child elements that have% as margin with inline-block

Tags: html, css

I want some elements on one line and get their parent to an equal size to the kids, the only problem is when I put % margin on the children, then they do not fit

It works with pixels in margin instead but I need to use % in this case to make it work responsively

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

html:

```
<div class="holder">

    <div class="blue">
    </div>

    <div class="red">
    </div>

     <div class="green">
    </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
.holder
{
    background-color:yellow;
    display:inline-block;
}

.holder > div
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:2%;
}

.blue
{
    background-color:blue;
}
.red
{
    background-color:red;
}

.green
{
    background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update below css. check link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankushkk/5e90qtxw/)

```
.holder
{
    background-color:yellow;
    display:inline-flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't...If you use `inline-block` then the `holder` div collapses to the width of the contents. So 2% would be OK but if you add in the 6% (3 * 2%) then the holder gets wider and the margin would then be increased...and so on and so on *ad infinitum*.

What happens is the `holder` div keeps it's original size (since it can't be calculated due to the infinity margin loop)  as though the 'extra space' wasn't applied but adds the margin in anyway (once) and the layout breaks.

SEE - [**http://jsfiddle.net/19s19oL7/**](http://jsfiddle.net/19s19oL7/)

AS mentioned by Ankush Kondhalkar `flexbox` is a solution although support is relatively limited at present. In the interim, use px and media queries.